# Redirect 301 Magento not working

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

**Note:** There are same questions already available in stackoverflow. I tried those but still not working.

What is my requirement is that if someone try to access our site with url

`http://oursite.com`

then it should redirect to

`http://www.oursite.com`

for the SEO purpose.

I am facing a problem with Redirect 301 in Magento. I tried to use

```
admin->System->Configuration->Web->Url Options->Auto-redirect to Base URL
```

and I have set it to **Yes (301 Moved Permanenty)** but still it is not working. I tried to edit .htaccess also with following code block

```
Redirect 301 http://oursite.com http://www.outsite.com
```

But still it is not working. I have no any idea about what could be the reason. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure

> Base URL = `http://www.oursite.com`

Then your redirect to base url should work

If you want to use .htaccess then try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.oursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```